# Every time I start my Hp Laptop I have to set up my ant_sel=1 setting on rtl8723be on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, rtl8723be

```
koolhussain@koolhussain-Notebook:~$ modinfo -p rtl8723be
swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0)
 (int)
koolhussain@koolhussain-Notebook:~$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
[sudo] password for koolhussain: 
koolhussain@koolhussain-Notebook:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
koolhussain@koolhussain-Notebook:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set this permanently by running in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"
```

Comment: Should i directly do this or after my old steps...???

Comment: It does not matter when to do it. This command will create a config that will apply the setting on boot.